# How can I return the different prices of my quantities?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have two tables, one containing all the quantities of products by country and another table that contains the prices by country.

When I add a condition for example country = "ch", I have the price correct for this country, I want to return different prices for all countries. How can I do that?

Here's my query:

```
SELECT 
    items.prod,
    items.qty_fr,
    items.date,
    products.price
FROM items
LEFT JOIN products
    ON products.product = items.prod
WHERE
    products.country = "CH"
GROUP BY
    items.prod
```

This is the result of my query:

It returns the first value

[image]

Here's my first table:

[image]

My second table :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT 
    products.country,
    items.prod,
    max(items.date) AS ItemDate,
    sum(products.price) AS ProductPrice 
FROM items
LEFT JOIN products on products.product = items.prod
group by products.country , items.prod
```

To add any more columns use an aggregation (sum, max etc) if its a numerical value else put it in the GROUP BY list